# Checking if OSX is on a 24 hour clock

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I would prefer to do this with Qt Methods if at all possible.

Currently in our code, we can distinguish that Windows is on a 24 hour clock; however not on Mac.

We have a method that returns a string such as: 1/9/2012 9:53:42 AM - Which is giving us a previous time, not the current one (Which is what we want), I do not want to mess with this method though.

I've been playing around with a way to determine if the current system clock is in military time; and to adjust the previous time returned from the string to reflect that. I can get this to work on Windows, but on Mac - it displays a normal 12-hour time regardless of whether we're on a 24-hour clock.

Ignore my crude-debugging messages or if I'm not particularly going at the problem correctly - I haven't been able to test it yet and tweak as necessary: (Explanation after code)

```
        QLocale *ql = new QLocale();
        QString qlTF = ql->timeFormat();
        QString fileTime = QString::fromUtf8(str.GetSafeStringPtr());
        if (qlTF.left(1) == (QString("H"))) // Our system clock is set to military time
        {
           QString newTime;
           QStringList fileTimeDateSplit = fileTime.split(" ");
           QStringList fileTimeSplit = fileTimeDateSplit.at(1).split(":");
           m_editModified->setText(qlTF);
           if (fileTimeSplit.at(0).toInt() < 12 && (fileTimeDateSplit.at(2) == "PM")) 
           {
              int newHour = 12 + (fileTimeSplit.at(0).toInt()%12);
              newTime.append(QString::number(newHour));
              newTime.append(":");
              newTime.append(fileTimeSplit.at(1));
              newTime.append(":");
              newTime.append(fileTimeSplit.at(2));
              m_editModified->setText(QString("military after noon"));
           }
        }
        else m_editModified->setText(qlTF);
```

Basically I'm grabbing the locale of the current machine to retrieve the system's time format. 
fileTime is set to a string such as "1/9/2012 9:53:42 AM". 
qlTF returns a format such as: HH:mm:ss , H:mm:ss, hh:mm:ss, or h:mm:ss - capital meaning it's a 24 hour clock. 
I tokenize the different strings by the delimiters and then check to see if the time was greater than 12 and PM; then add the additional time and combine the new time string.

You can see that I did:

```
m_editModified->setText(qlTF);
```

for debugging purposes. On Windows, this will be set to HH:mm:ss; however even with a 24-hour clock enabled on a mac, it still returns h:mm:ss - which completely defeats the purpose.

Any ideas would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just convert the string you have ("1/9/2012 9:53:42 AM") to QDateTime and then convert that QDateTime back to string in the format you want (I use ISODate in the example):

```
QString timeFormat = "M/d/yyyy h:m:s AP";
QDateTime dt = QDateTime::fromString("1/9/2012 9:53:42 AM", timeFormat);

QString text = "";
if (dt.isValid())
    text = dt.toString(Qt::ISODate);
```

Comment: The string I have isn't being reported into a 24-hour format; otherwise I would just use that and be done with it :p. So I'm trying to figure out how to find out if the system is on a 24-hour clock; but I'll definitely keep the suggestion in mind for my formatting purposes!

Comment: Do you know the exact format of the string you get or not? In my example, 12-hour format is used for the time. If the AM is changed to PM, the example still works. If the string you get is formatted using the current locale, can't you use the datetime format of the locale to convert the string back to QDateTime.

Comment: No - I don't know the exact format of the string on OSX, that's the original question :) Sure, I can check if it says PM and would be able to change it - but I still don't know what type of format the system clock is on and *if* I should change it. Thanks though!

Comment: If you don't know the format, then the 12h/24h isn't your only problem. The date used in your example could be either September 1 or January 9. The best way to fix the problem would be to fix the method that returns these datetimes in unknown format. The best return value would of course be QDateTime, but if the return value must be a string, ISO 8601 format (Qt::ISODate) is a good choice.

Comment: Thanks for your input; but my OP only manipulates the time - not the date; so I don't need to know that format, I only need a way to figure out if the clock is on a 12 or 24 hour clock for the system.